# How to convert raw H.264 in Annex B format to AVCC using FFMPEG command line

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

Hi was trying to find the command line parameters to pass into  FFMPEG to convert raw H.264 file in ANNEX B format to AVCC format but I can't find anything on the internet. I only found the reverse (AVCC to ANNEX B). So I'm asking here
Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be ffmpeg -i input.h264 -c:v copy output.mp4

Comment: There needs to be a container, like mp4, to use avcc.

Comment: Yes, there is no bitstream filter for this sequence.

Comment: @MarkusSchumann, that did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following command line: ffmpeg -i input.h264 -c:v copy output.mp4